# Apache: Using VirtualHost redirect to URL with RewriteCond applied?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, httpd.conf

So I have a RewriteCond that turns:

```
domain.com/view.php?a=1
```

into:

```
domain.com/artist/name
```

I have a shorter domain: `dmn.com` that I would like to provide shortlinks for artists:

```
dmn.com/name
```

How can I get `dmn.com/name` to redirect to: `domain.com/artist/name` while keeping the shortlink in tact?

.htaccess:

```
#rewrite profile requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule artist/(.*)$ view.php?a=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ // <-- ??? not sure what to put here
    ServerName dmn.com
    ServerAlias www.dmn.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Since the directory "/artist" doesn't actually exist (since it's being rewritten), I can't seem to put `/var/www/html/artist` in the DocumentRoot of the VirtualHost config without Apache spitting back:

```
Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/html/artist] does not exist
```

Comment: @msg this works, but is there any way to keep the shortlink path in the URL?

Comment: For example, typing in `dmn.com/name` keeps that exact URL in the address bar but internally redirects to `domain.com/artist/name` -- right now with the solution you provided, the URL is redirected to the long url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is not an actual redirection, but another rewrite.

You can't do it with a separate `VirtualHost`. Well, you can if you point it to the same `DocumentRoot` and duplicate your rules or load them from a common file, either via `.htaccess` or a `Include` directive.

You can also add the short domain name to your main domain `ServerAlias`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # This should point to your current config
    DocumentRoot /var/www/artists_profiles/
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com ex.com www.ex.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you add the new rules to the top of the file:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ex.com
RewriteRule ^(^.*) artist/$1
```

Then your existing rules should pick up. If you want to avoid the shortened domain from responding to the longer urls you could add a similar `RewriteCond` to the existing rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !ex.com
```

Comment: I've combined the vhosts which works, thanks. But the rewrite rule doesn't seem to be working. Added to the top of the .htaccess, but going to `dmn.com/name` gives a 404 saying it can't find `/name` - making me think it's not getting sent to `/artist/name`

Comment: No, it was my fault. New server install and `AllowOverride` was set to `None` instead of `All` .. the .htaccess file wasn't even being read. Thanks for the help, everything is working perfectly.